# jQuery image slider with different sized images

Tags: jquery, images

All of the jQuery image sliders I've seen require images to be the same size.

Do you know any which can dynamically resize their display pane to fit the size of the image.  I have seen this done on commercial websites.

Comment: Can you link to an example of the sort of slider you're looking for?

Comment: Are you talking about responsive sliders that resize to fit the width of the browser window?

Comment: @Steve, I updated my answer to a slider that has auto-height and width along with demos check it out

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for the same thing and came across this... http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/examples/variable-visible-variable-size.php - it was the easiest to use and fully customizable.

Not sure if you found what you were looking for already, but just in case someone else is looking for the same thing - it may help.

Comment: link is broken, can you fix it?

Comment: The link doesn't work now.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a slider which has auto-height capability and auto-width

http://webbies.dk/SudoSlider/demos.html

Demo
http://webbies.dk/SudoSlider/assets/files/SudoSlider/package/demos/autoheight.html

This also has auto-height capability http://slidesjs.com/
See the `autoHeight` option